# Generate Fmbalbuena Numbers

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence, decision-problem

My user id is `106959`

How to check if the number is Fmbalbuena number?

First Step: Check if the number of digits is a multiple of 3: `6` = `3` * `2`

Second step: Split the digits into even thirds: `106959 -> 10 69 59`

Third step: Subtract the first set of digits from the second modulo 10: `6` - `1` = `5`, `9` - `0` = `9`

Last step: Check that the result is the same as the third set of digits: `59 = 59`

### Sequence

Here is the sequence until `106959`

```
109, 110, 121, 132, 143, 154, 165, 176, 187, 198, 208, 219, 220, 231, 242, 253, 264, 275, 286, 297, 307, 318, 329, 330, 341, 352, 363, 374, 385, 396, 406, 417, 428, 439, 440, 451, 462, 473, 484, 495, 505, 516, 527, 538, 549, 550, 561, 572, 583, 594, 604, 615, 626, 637, 648, 659, 660, 671, 682, 693, 703, 714, 725, 736, 747, 758, 769, 770, 781, 792, 802, 813, 824, 835, 846, 857, 868, 879, 880, 891, 901, 912, 923, 934, 945, 956, 967, 978, 989, 990, 100090, 100191, 100292, 100393, 100494, 100595, 100696, 100797, 100898, 100999, 101000, 101101, 101202, 101303, 101404, 101505, 101606, 101707, 101808, 101909, 102010, 102111, 102212, 102313, 102414, 102515, 102616, 102717, 102818, 102919, 103020, 103121, 103222, 103323, 103424, 103525, 103626, 103727, 103828, 103929, 104030, 104131, 104232, 104333, 104434, 104535, 104636, 104737, 104838, 104939, 105040, 105141, 105242, 105343, 105444, 105545, 105646, 105747, 105848, 105949, 106050, 106151, 106252, 106353, 106454, 106555, 106656, 106757, 106858, 106959
```

You can generate the first N numbers, infinite numbers, Check if the number is Fmbalbuena number or get Nth number of the sequence

### Test cases

Truthy

```
106959
109
219
103222
666666000
777666999
```

Falsy

```
100
230
320
666666666
125466
1069592
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>13</s> <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
ḍ₃\-ᵐtᵛ0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NZZNimVFEIW38qhxtUTGX0ZOdCHqoBV/Bg1C29JI2xMF0YHg3AU4ddIg7qZqI@U5caNqkHkf737n3ZsRX1BfvH755bc/vvruG3169/bu9uLj293bT949/vrP48@/PP72992b1z989dHdT7z8@uWr73H9/uG/398/fPjz6eHfP3DTZy9w/ebhw1/y9PTpkjxx7m9LsOjqK1PV@1v2n4jc3/beuDynv8VnNSym8nwT/vCNhvfeidqRBNaEryW8iR@N37phCceSgWUTrY3lFH5Bah5HtX8QmDowDWCawHQD0wKmB5gJl1V8MGDWj@jALIBZArMNzAqYHWAuXBYwV2BuwNyBeQDzBOYbmBcwP8BCuCxgocDCgIUDiwAWCSw2sChgcYClcFnAUoGlAUsHljx0HC@WDSyLJ36AbeGygG0Ftg3YdmA7gO08LAdrUsA2z7mEywJWCqwMWDmwCmCVwGoDqwJWB9gRLgvYUWDHgB0HdgLYSWBnAzsF7Bzpssvs63RFRa8ai/GpsTvfF3vwpLDn6WaQzepgL9YV@7TR6s7CvqTzlkrnLZPOWy6dt/rQsad03trSeauk89bp5hKV7i/RdXWc6uo8tE7nqa/O01idp7k6T/fqPK3VeXpGAtHOs6tlRwrspp1nrp2H9uo86wJj39p5Vtp5drTzXKzzfFnnubYF4mad526d52Gd52mdhxbsPC/rPD/WeSHeebG886L1wG4tloR750V450V650U3E/byzkObdl5KdB6atfNSo/PSovPS21XJiM7LjEv2HZ2XFfUsP2VnSJ9Yv14/S4M9IjaR4v1sBu3Zw2PuM1G@gPLXlJNBORmUk0HZQcay22rFaTffuh/ROBSMQ8E4FIxt5@wVZ2Fd226KzfdyzgPnPHDOA2evBhss2A3B0oW12HSaoyA4CoKjoBs82ZXdQsl6J4uT3k5TZ06B5BRIWrHZypt9t9kkXdHN49/ROtNkDoBNlYr9X2zWYmcV26BYsz7gyjZ50WT6S2kOO/ywHQ9757DQh1U5dP/slniNxGsk1pHYRmIfiWMkzpF4j8Q1Ej/Lu0ZeHXlt5PWRN0beHHn3yFsj75VzRloZaddIqyOtjbQ@0sZImyPtHmnrkhYzSUbeNfLqyGsjr4@8MfLmyLtH3hp5ryFwRloZaddIqyOtjbQ@0sZImyPtHmnrkhYzUkbeNfLqyGsjr4@8MfLmyLtH3hp5ryFwRloZaddIqyOtjbQ@0sZImyPtHmnr@h8AM1s@/x8) ([infinite sequence version](https://tio.run/##ATEAzv9icmFjaHlsb2cy/@KEleKJnOKGsOKCgSbhuoniiqX/4biN4oKDXC3htZB04bWbMP//))

Not sure how I missed that by making it about congruence to 0, I dodged any thorny sign issues in taking the last digit versus performing a proper mod 10.

```
ḍ₃          Split the input into three digit lists of similar lengths.
  \         Check that the lengths are strictly equal, and transpose.
    ᵐ       For each triple,
   -        subtract the second digit from the sum of the first and third.
     tᵛ0    Is the last digit of every difference 0?
```

Comment: Finally `ᵛ` is useful for something!

Comment: @Fatalize I haven't been too active with Brachylog lately, but `ᵛ` has always felt pretty useful to me--granted, a lot of the time it ends up being `≡ᵛ`, which can usually be equivalent to `=h`. I'd say the real standout here is how `-` generalizes to longer lists: it seems like it should broadly be the more useful behavior than, say, reducing by subtraction, but I can't say I remember the last time it actually came up.

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>14</s> 13 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

Checks if a given number is a Fmbalbuena:

```
S3äR`-T%Q*g3Ö
```

Could be 12 bytes by taking the input as a list of digits, removing the leading `S`.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/2PjwkqAE3RDVQK1048PT/v83NDCzNLUEAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfaXL/2Djw0uCEnRDVAO10o0PT/uv8z/a0MDM0tRSx9DAUsfIEEQbGxkZ6ZiBgYGBgY65uTmQZWlpCRIDcgwNDXUMdAx1jIFKDXSMjA10jI0MoOqBQMfQyNQERIGNNYJqAmqPBQA).

We can add a leading `∞ʒD` to output the infinite sequence:
[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Uce8U5PSjQ9Pqz01Kdj48JKgBN0Q1cD//wE)

**Explanation:**

```python
S          # Split the (implicit) input-integer to a list of digits
 3ä        # (Try to) split it into three equal-sized parts
   R       # Reverse these parts from [A,B,C] to [C,B,A]
    `      # Pop and push all three lists separated to the stack
     -     # Subtract the digits of the top two lists: B-A
      T%   # Modulo-10
        Q  # Check if it's equal to C: B-A=C (1 if truthy; 0 if falsey)
*          # Multiply this by the (implicit) input-integer
           # (remains unchanged if the check was truthy or becomes 0 otherwise)
 g         # Pop and push its length
  3Ö       # Check if this is divisible by 3
           # (after which it is output implicitly as result)
```

```python
∞          # Push an infinite positive list: [1,2,3,...]
 ʒ         # Filter it by:
  D        #  Duplicate the current integer
   S3äR`-T%Q*g3Ö
           #  Same as above
           # (after which the filtered infinite list is output implicitly as result)
```

Comment: Test cases are added, can you change the test cases?

Comment: @Fmbalbuena Done, although one of your test cases is incorrect.

Comment: Edited a test case

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 66 bytes

Expects the input number as a string. Returns a Boolean value.

```javascript
n=>![...n].some((d,i)=>i<(l=n.length/3)&(n[i+=l]-d+10)%10!=n[i+l])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZDNDoIwEITvvgVNNG2QWlqBNLEcfQJvlQPh39TWAJr49AicNFnnON9mMrO3/JUPRd89xsC6sppqNVmVeppSajM6uHuFcbnviEq7EzbKUlPZZmwPguyw1Z2vTBaUfsjINmSeWhyTkalwdnCmosY1GOlL/xzbd4bI5tuvMQpZLCOJCAAgl4fwreCcAyBexRgDWJIkM5NyDfyB6Gr1OTcD3BfK4gJyBWd/O82ChvDoCIP1TcvE6QM)

#### How?

We don't explicitly test whether the length of the input number is a multiple of 3. When it's not, `l` is a non-integer value, both `n[i+l]` and `n[i+2*l]` are *undefined*, `n[i+l]-d+10` is *NaN*, and we end up testing `NaN != undefined`, which is true and makes the test fail as expected.

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>19</s> 14 bytes

```
L3/₌ẎȯI÷‟-ȧ₀%⁼
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJMMy/igozhuo7Ir0nDt+KAny3Ip+KCgCXigbwiLCIiLCJbMSwgMCwgNiwgOSwgNSwgOSwgMl0iXQ==)

Checks whether an input number is a Fmbalbuena number. Takes input as a list of digits.

*can't believe I forgot to handle the case where the length isn't divisible by 3...*

*-5 thanks to Fmbalbuena*

### Explained

```
L3/₌ẎȯI÷‟-ȧ₀%⁼
L                   # Push the length of the input
 3/                 # divide that by 3
   ₌Ẏȯ              # and push input[0:that], input[that:-1]
      I             # split input[that:-1] into two lists
       ÷            # and dump that onto the stack - the stack is now [first N/3, remaining first half, remaining second half]
        ‟           # rotate the stack right - this sets it up for the subtraction
         -ȧ         # subtract the first N/3 digits from the second half and take the absolute value
           ₀%       # and modulo by 10
             ⁼      # does that exactly equal the first half?
```

Comment: The input must be a number

Comment: @Fmbalbuena [no it doesn't](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18097/78850)

Comment: just kidding, explain?

Comment: I'm working on that right now lol

Comment: Falis on `[1, 0, 6, 9, 5, 9, 1]` the input must be zero, not non-one

Comment: @Fmbalbuena shh I totally didn't forget to account for the case where the input isn't divisible by 3

Comment: [-5 bytes](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJMMy/igozhuo7Ir0nDt+KAny3Ip+KCgCXigbwiLCIiLCJbMSwgMCwgNiwgOSwgNSwgOV0iXQ==)

Comment: Why you don't edit that?

Comment: @Fmbalbuena I just need a second to change the explanation lol

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133158/discussion-between-lyxal-and-fmbalbuena).

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 27 bytes

```
¬∨﹪Ｌθ³⊙∕θ³﹪⍘⭆³§§⪪θ÷Ｌθ³λκ±¹χ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU1BCsIwEPyKxykotBSF4knxUrBV6AtCs6TBkLRxLfr6mNB6cGF2hmVnph@E750wIdy9tozWMW4ejZMv43Alq3jAlG03ZcTJfnDRs5aEabmsf2fxpI5jgMJCjRhRRgPXVtIbP@5Gozl5a8tr0F9FXCbikURLSjChSLrIszTHEIr8UO2rsJvNFw) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs a Charcoal boolean, i.e. `-` if the input is an Fmbalbuena number, nothing if not. Explanation:

```
    θ                       Input as a string
   Ｌ                        Length
  ﹪  ³                      Is not divisible by `3`
 ∨                          Logical Or
        θ                   Input as a string
       ∕ ³                  Reduced to a third in length
      ⊙                     Any index satisfies
             ³              Literal integer `3`
            ⭆               Map over implicit range and join
                 θ          Input string
                ⪪ ÷Ｌθ³      Split into three parts
               §            Indexed by
                      λ     Inner value
              §             Indexed by
                       κ    Outer index
           ⍘            ±¹  Interpreted as base `-1`
          ﹪               χ Is not divisible by `10`
¬                           Logical Not
                            Implicitly print
```

Comment: `666777999` must give `-` because `6` - `7` gives `-1` and mod by 10 gives `9`

Comment: @Fmbalbuena Then it wouldn't work for your user id, because `0` - `9` gives `-9` and mod by 10 gives `1`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `grouping.extras`, <s>75</s> 45 bytes

```
[ 3 n-group first3 spin v- [ 10 rem ] map = ]
```

Returns whether or not the input is a Fmbalbuena number.

[image]

### Explanation

```
                   ! { 1 0 6 9 5 9 }
3 n-group          ! { { 1 0 } { 6 9 } { 5 9 } }
first3             ! { 1 0 } { 6 9 } { 5 9 }
spin               ! { 5 9 } { 6 9 } { 1 0 }
v-                 ! { 5 9 } { 5 9 }
[ 10 rem ] map     ! { 5 9 } { 5 9 }
=                  ! t
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 14 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Dœs3µZI%⁵z-Ḣ⁼Ṫ
```

A monadic Link accepting a positive integer that yields `1` if it is Fmbalbuena, or `0` if not.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/l6ORi40NbozxVHzVurdJ9uGPRo8Y9D3eu@n90z@H2R01r3P//jzY0MLM0tdRRMDQAEkaGYJaxkZGRjoIZGBgYGOgomJubA5mWlmBZIN/IGEgYGxnAFAEBUMbI1ARMg000igUA)**
Or test every positive integer up to and including \$106959\$ [here](https://tio.run/##AS4A0f9qZWxsef//RMWTczPCtVpJJeKBtXot4bii4oG84bmq/8OH4oKsVP//MTA2OTU5).

#### How?

```
Dœs3µZI%⁵z-Ḣ⁼Ṫ - Link: positive integer, I
D              - digits of I
   3           - literal three
 œs            - split the digits into three equal(ish) parts
                  (if not equally splittable leftmost get longer first)
    µ          - start a new monadic chain with X=that as the argument
             Ṫ - tail X (gets the digits in the last part and modifies X)
     Z         - transpose the remaining parts
      I        - deltas
        ⁵      - literal ten
       %       - modulo (the deltas)
          -    - literal minus one
         z     - transpose with filler -1 (avoiding false positives like 1009)
           Ḣ   - head
            ⁼  - does that equal the tail we removed?
```

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 65 bytes

```r
function(x,y=matrix(x,,3))!any((y[,2]-y[,1])%%10-y[,3],sum(x,-y))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZLBCsIwDIbvvoWHQQMdtqnbqKNPIhPq5lBwFeYG7dPXrgfPxhxCDv@X/AmZ4zjZ53W9OWviuLp@ebwc8zyYyS7zw6eSK4C9dYGxcObYlSnLDopCiq1UHX@vU5KVASB6I0WtK90OxheHJLkw19/tzDycZCkz1X4nsgF2G0GSoyR2V4hIIeocQggK1DRNgrQmeMvmSENQkeQKBX3vFKTzYnUkEvlB8J/j/s7EDw)

Input as list of digits; checks whether this is a 'Fmalbuena' number.
[+24 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZY/NCoMwDMfve4sdCimrLE2n0oFPMhx0MjdBK4hCfXqXeZl1OYTkl/zzMSx159rH9PSuWOrJV2PTewhqLjo3Dk2AIM5C4x3w2vYvjRCkFAyUMlIeffV2AyMhzMn5GWC@KSoT9rpc276hKeVvCWjMbGrlYUuilPSuaohoS7LVEHEL8zxnaC1rI3HURCZKDeH/XLZoPaWXHVkf4IuWDw) for input as integer.

Pretty straightforward, except that we can check whether length of `x` is divisible by 3 using `sum(x,-y)` instead of `length(x)%%3` (or its usual [R](https://www.r-project.org/) golf `sum(x|1)%%3`), since we know that all elements of `x` must be non-negative, and the first one must be positive.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python3](https://python.org), 246 bytes

This can probably be cut down a bit, but I didn't see a Python answer, so I thought I'd try it out. Just counting the actual code in the byte count, not the characters assigning the `n` variable.

```
n=106959
c=lambda:int(len(str(n))/3);f=lambda z,x,y:int(list(z[x])[y])
j=str(n);a=[j,list(j),len(list(j))];
if(len(a[0])%3==0):z=[a[0][x:x+c()]for x in range(0,a[2],c())];p="%s%s"%(f(z,1,0)-f(z,0,0),f(z,1,1)-f(z,0,1));print(p==z[-1:][0])
else:print(False)
```

Answer (score 0):

## J, 64 bytes

Check whether a number is Fmbalbuena. The input is a number as a string, for example `'219'`. Yield `1` if the number is Fmbalbuena, `0` otherwise.

```
([:>(2{])((9|~[)=9|~])&.>(1{])-&.>0{])(]$~3,3%~#)".&.>(#$1<;.1])

                                                      (#$1<;.1]) split into digits (characters)
                                                 ".&.> convert digits into real digits
                                      (]$~3,3%~#) reshape into thirds
([:>(2{])((9|~[)=9|~])&.>(1{])-&.>0{]) substract modulo 9 and check for equality
```

It can probably golfed a lot more but I am helpless when it comes to performing operations on cells.